What is the natural map →∏?
I am referring to this post. It gives a "natural" map ${→∏ _}$. But what is it? Is it ok if I consider this map in this way: ${m \longmapsto (m/1,m/1,...)}$?

Yes, you've got the right map.

Yes. In general, homomorphisms into a product are classified by families of homomorphisms into the individual factors, this is the universal property of the product. This is why here it is enough to specify homomorphisms $M \to M_{\mathfrak{p}}$. But these come from the definition of the localization. And yes you can write it as $m \mapsto m/1$.
In general, as one progresses to learn algebra (or any other topic for that matter), one has to be able to work with homomorphisms "abstractly" without always referring to the elements of the modules. The explicit description of the homomorphism in terms of elements is almost never used in this example. You only need to know that it is the (unique) homomorphism whose components are the natural inclusions into the localization.
